# What is the use of `native-border-router` in Contiki folder?

Tags: sensors, contiki, iot

Can anyone explain what is native-border-router example in Contiki and how it is useful where to use it, I used and run rpl-border-router example and understood it but I don't know how this will work. Please help and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically they are the same, the difference is that the native border router runs most of the code on the computer side and gets raw farmes from the radio over the serial line it is connected to. At least this is how i understand it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a critical difference:

> The border router will receive the prefix through a [SLIP][1] (Serial Line Interface Protocol) connection and it will be communicated to the rest of the nodes in the RPL network.

http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/RPL_Border_Router

> This code connects a 802.15.4 radio over TTY with the full uIPv6 stack of Contiki including 6LoWPAN and 802.15.4 framing / parsing. The native border router also acts as a RPL Root and handles the routing and maintains the RPL network. ***Finally the native border router connects the full 6LoWPAN/RPL network to the host (linux/os-x) network stack making it possible for applications on the host to transparently reach all the nodes in the 6LoWPAN/RPL network***.

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/ipv6/native-border-router